# How do you use ADF PipelineParameters with ML studio to change output location instead of input location

Tags: python, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to parameterise my ML studio pipeline such that it outputs to a different blob store depending on which ADF environment it is being run from - the dev or prod ADF instance. This is so that the data engineers can have an output on their dev blob storage so they can avoid developing in live, while still using the exact same ML Studio pipeline as would be used in live.

I have followed the instructions in [this notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-showcasing-datapath-and-pipelineparameter.ipynb) to change the input data source on blob dynamically using PipelineParameters.

Can I / how do I do the same for output locations?

Below is the code I used. I have used ./outputs as the output folder. I want to change this to a location in blob storage dynamically set via a PipelineParameter that can be called from ADF. (Or another way if you have other suggestions!)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```python
from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath, DataPathComputeBinding
from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineParameter

default_data_path = DataPath(
    datastore=Datastore(workspace, "prod_data_science"), 
    path_on_datastore='path/to/data/')

input_datapath_pipeline_param = PipelineParameter(name="input_datapath", default_value=default_data_path)

input_data_consumption = (
    input_datapath_pipeline_param, 
    DataPathComputeBinding(
        mode='mount',
        overwrite = True
    )
)

toy_step = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="toy_code.py",
    source_directory="./",
    arguments=[
        '--input_folder', input_data_consumption,
        '--output_folder', './outputs',
    ],
    inputs=[input_data_consumption],
    runconfig=runconfig,
)
```

Comment: to set the output of a `PythonScriptStep` to upload to a storage account you  need to setup an `OutputFileDatasetConfig` and then pass it in to the `PythonScriptStep` instead of the `'./outputs'` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-move-data-in-out-of-pipelines#read-outputfiledatasetconfig-as-inputs-to-non-initial-steps

Comment: Yep, I have done that. However that location is fixed when I set up the pipeline; it's not dynamically assignable by ADF unless I have missed something?

Comment: Your python script step is not taking a variable input for the output argument! So it cannot be dynamic in the examplemyou provided. And for you to be able to pass in a parameter from ADF into the AML pipeline you need to define pipeline parameter object first, just like you did for your input path then map this to other objects and steps in the AML pipeline.